# Graph Theory Question - length of path vs. independent sets

Tags: graph-theory

Hello there and sorry for the blurry title, if someone has a better title for me after reading my question, I'll be glad to hear.

If there's a need to check for a given graph G with n nodes (n>10), that for every 2 nodes there's a simple path of length at least 10 between them, does it enough to check if there isn't an independent set in size more than 10?

If not, how can I check it in the graph?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello! Your question is quite confusing to me. Could you perhaps state a bit more precisely what you want?

Comment: @Jernej,  
I need to find how to determine for a given graph, that for every 2 nodes in it, there's a simple path between them in length of at least 10

Comment: And how do you need to determine that? By an algorithm/computer or is this an analytical question?

Comment: @Jernej  
algorithm, a turing machine actually

Comment: You can do that easily if you do  not have any computational restraints. Given $u,v \in V(G)$ take any subset $S$ of $V(G) \setminus \{u,v\}$ of cardinality > 10 and check if there is a simple path from $u$ to $v$ that uses $S$

Comment: @Jernej I need an algorithm that will be in polyomial time, that's my only restraint. and How do I check if there is a simple path? BFS?

Answer (score 3):

For a (presumably connected) graph $G$ with $n > 10$ nodes, you ask whether the maximal size of an independent set being at most 10 implies that between any two nodes there's a path of length at least 10.  The answer is no.  Consider the star with 10 leaves, $K_{1,10}$; the maximal size of an independent set is 10, but the maximal length of a path is 2.  If you meant to say the maximal size of an independent set was less than 10, the answer is still no: just add any edge between two leaves of $K_{1,10}$.